# Multiplayer game with (Java socket write/readObject)

Tags: java, sockets

Client and server have two data streams (ObjectOutputStream\ObjectInputStream).
I'm trying to exchange objects of different classes. But I can not understand how to implement it correctly.

If I had one class, it would look like this:

```
MyClass c = (MyClass)in.readObject();
```

But I have to exchange objects of different classes. How to take them correctly?
It may be possible to somehow determine what class came to me in readObject()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you use `instanceof`

```
Object obj = in.readObject();
if (obj instaneof MyClass) {
    MyClass c = (MyClass) obj;
    process(c);
} else if (obj instanceof MyOtherClass) {
    // etc
```